# Export all Tables and Views from a database (data dump)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I understood that you could not do a full snowflake data dump and need to use the COPY command to unload data from a table into an internal (i.e. Snowflake) stage.

To automate the process, I thought to do it with Python. Do you think that is the best method?

```
import traceback
import snowflake.connector
import pandas as pd
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

url = URL(
    user='??????',
    password='????????',
    account='??????-??????',
    database='SNOWFLAKE',
    role = 'ACCOUNTADMIN'
)

out_put_string = ""

try:
    engine = create_engine(url)
    connection = engine.connect()
    
    # Get all the views from the SNOWFLAKE database
    query = '''
        show views in database SNOWFLAKE
    '''
    df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)

    # Loop over all the views
    df = df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        out_put_string +=  "VIEW:----------" + row['schema_name'] + "." + row['name'] + "----------\n"
        df_view = pd.read_sql('select * from ' + row['schema_name'] + "." + row['name'], connection)
        df_view.to_csv("/Temp/Output_CVS/" + row['schema_name'] + "-" + row['name'] + ".csv")
        out_put_string += df_view.to_string() + "\n"

except:
    print("ERROR:")
    traceback.print_exc()

connection.close()

#Export all the Views in one file
text_file = open("/Temp/Output_CVS/AllViewsData.txt", "w")
text_file.write(out_put_string)
text_file.close()
```

Comment: In what context are you asking - performance, language use, storage consumption or anything else. 'Best' is very subjective and use-case dependent.

Comment: The "best" way might be to keep the data in Snowflake.  What is the purpose of unloading everything in Snowflake to external files?

Comment: Good point about the context. My context was to understand better what kind of data is stored in the Snowflake database. It's more of a learning context for now. But I also agree that the data should stay in Snowflake anyway. Thank you for your comments Pankaj & Mike